# Oracle SQL in HR Schema Write a query to display “How many characters are there in each employee’s last name before the first 'e' or 'E' appears?”

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a query to display “How many characters are there in each employee’s last name
before the first 'e' or 'E' appears?”

Comment: Send your data structure and some input data and also send what you expected from that data.

Comment: please take a tour before asking a question about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The current one smells like a homework of multiple choice type question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty much what the built in function `INSTR()` does - well, technically, it finds the positions of the `'e'` so what you want is one less than that number.

To be safe, you can write this as:

```
select instr(lower(last_name) || 'e', 'e') - 1
```

This concatenates the `'e'` to the name to be sure it returns all characters when there is no `'e'`.

Comment: Thanks its  so helpful.